# concatenate words of a string by comparing with words of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, algorithm

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Glue words</title>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="textbase">
        Write text to fix after. je suis gen til l ol
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="gluefct()">Tokenize</button>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
function gluefct() {

    var space = " ";
    var glueArray = ["jesuis", "gentil", "lol"];
    var stringBase = document.getElementById("textbase").value;
    var newString = "";

    for (gluewords in glueArray) {
        var arrayofstring = stringBase.split(" ");
        var numberelement = arrayofstring.length; 
        var i = 0;

        while (i < numberelement) {
            var motactuel = arrayofstring[i];
            var n = i;

            while (motactuel.length < gluewords.length) {
                n = n+1;
                motactuel = motactuel + arrayofstring[n];
            }

            if (motactuel == gluewords) {
                newString = newString + motactuel + space;
                i = n+1;
            }

            else {
                newString = newString + arrayofstring[i] + space;
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }

        stringBase = newString;
        newString = "";
    }

    document.getElementById("textbase").value = stringBase;
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to stick words from a string who had been separated by checking with the complete words from an array of strings.

For example:

Here is my array:

```
var glueArray = ["jesuis", "gentil", "lol"];
```

And here is my string:

```
"je suis gen til lo l et voilà"
```

This should be the result of the function:

```
"jesuis gentil lol et voilà"
```

I don't see what's wrong with my code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if how you are doing it is **best**, but your code only has a small problem. You are using a hash for glueArray which means that you are assigning key values of 0 to "jesuis" and 1 to "gentil", etc. When you use the for loop to go through the array you are getting the index values and NOT the words. I suggest this small fix which seems to work.

```
//your code before
for (glueIndice in glueArray) {
    var gluewords = glueArray[glueIndice];
    var arrayofstring = stringBase.split(" ");
//your code after
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do as follows;

```js
var reference = ["jesuis", "gentil", "lol"],
          str = "je su is gen til    lo l et    voilà",
       result = str.split(/\s+/)
                   .reduce((p,c,i,a) => { var testStr = p[p.length-1] + c;
                                          reference.some(s => s.indexOf(testStr) !== -1) ? p[p.length-1] = testStr
                                                                                         : p.push(c);
                                          return p;
                                        },[""])
                   .join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

It first takes the str and splits it into an array by taking white space(s) as a delimiter.

In reduce we will take every word (`c`) one by one and join it with the previous one (`p[p.length-1]`) to generate a test string (`testStr`).

If `testStr` is found in the `reference` array's items we will replace the last item in the `p` array with it's "concatenated with the next word" version.  If `testStr` is not found in the `reference` array's items we will push the current word (`c`) to the `p` array. And return `p` for the next turn.

Comment: You should explain your answer. Also, this seems to assume that there will only be one space separating a word. I think your backtracking will need to be a loop.

Comment: @popo63301 what browser are you using? The above snippet uses arrow function which might result syntax error if the environment you are running it is not ES6 compatible.

Comment: @squint it should be fine with multiple white spaces though (`str.split(/\s+/)`) however you are right... i will attach an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if the word is broken in more than one place, like `je su is` instead of `je suis`.

Comment: @squint i modified the snippet to cover that case.